# array containing two arrays with no key

Tags: php, arrays

I was bug squashing my script when I discovered that an array (`$array`) contained two arrays with no key like so:

```
array(19) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "243"
  ["var"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}

array(10) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(243)
}
```

They both contain different data, i just removed most of it to show what I'm talking about. Now I will find the cause of this eventually and fix it, but what I need is a temporary fix to get the value of `var` from the first array. Currently when I use print_r and var_dump I do get the actual value of `var` but also a `NULL`. For that reason I can't seem to store the value of `var` in a variable.

Any ideas?

Here is the full array (with some sensitive data masked)

```
Array
(
    [id] => 243
    [ordering] => 0
    [state] => 1
    [checked_out] => 203
    [checked_out_time] => 2013-07-17 14:28:15
    [status] => new
    [order_id] => 84
    [username] => 267
    [ankleside] => left
    [engraving] => left
    [serial] => 152
    [color_padding] => left
    [color_shell] => left
    [scan] => SCAN_2013-07-17_xxxxxx_X_hotmail.com_LEFT.PNG
    [workfile] => WORK_2013-07-17_xxxxxx_X_hotmail.com_LEFT.png
    [stlfile] => 2013-07-17_xxxxxx_X_hotmail.com_LEFT_.jpg
    [timespent] =>
    [created_by] => 203
)

Array
(
    [id] => 243
    [status] => new
    [username] => 267
    [ankleside] => left
    [engraving] => left
    [scan] => SCAN_2013-07-17_xxxxxxx_X_hotmail.com_LEFT.PNG
    [workfile] =>
    [stlfile] => fb-foto.png
    [issues] =>
)
```

Comment: Aren't "id" and "var" the keys?

Comment: you have a proper ID on both arrays being 243 the id however on 1 its in int on the other it is as string.

Comment: They is no such thing as "an array with no key". Every element of an array has a corresponding key. The output shown above is the result of two separate variables passed to `var_dump()`

Comment: @StephenTG they are for each of their arrays, but the two arrays themselves don't have keys. So when I try to get the value of a key which is in the first array and not in the second array, I can't store that in a variable

Comment: When you do `var_dump($string)` it doesn't show a numerical key for each of those arrays?

Comment: Is the code you've posted the result of doing var_dump() on $array?

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm just passing a single variable to `var_dump()`, but it throws out two arrays. So what I mean with "an array with no key" is that I can't select the array which I want, since there are apparently two of them

Comment: please show us your PHP-code to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: @Ortix92 so you have 2 arrays being 1 a complete array and the other an incomplete one with the same data ? Would be better if you show the complete dump of either print_r or var_dump.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't inside a loop or something making it `var_dump()` twice? Try adding `echo "done";` after the `var_dump();`

Comment: You say you've removed some data - did you remove the "var" element from the second array? If not, that's probably why you get "test" and NULL - it doesn't exist in the second one.

Comment: @Ortix92 `I'm just passing a single variable to var_dump()` - That is simply not possible. Are you sure you're not calling it in a loop?

Comment: [Merge the two arrays based on unique fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660675/php-array-merge-array-unique)

Comment: Wow.. apparently it's called twice! But there is no `for-loop` in my code anywhere that's why i didn't think of that. Maybe somewhere in a parent class somewhere :S Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys!

Comment: I thought that php array values always have keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow `var_dump();` is called twice. Try adding `echo "done";` after `var_dump($array);` to verify.

You could also add `debug_print_backtrace();` to help you see how it is called twice.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

Comment: At this point, it's probably just hidden somewhere in a (likely sizeable) chunk of code. Seems like it's just a matter of hunting it down, not really what SO is for...

Comment: @steven there is no point. It's 200 lines of code which I'm sure you don't want to sift through. And on top of that, the method returns to a parent method which is another 600 lines of code. There are no loops in my method. So it must be in the parent

Comment: @Ortix92 see updated answer, try `debug_print_backtrace();` might help you figure it out.