# How to merge 2 arrays other

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays.Example : `$array_1(a,b,c)` and `$array_2(a,b,d,e)`
I want merge `$array_1 and $array_2` .result : `$array(a,b,c,d,e)`
How to do that ?. Help me !. Thanks u

Comment: $array=array_unique(array_merge($array_1,$array_2 ));


[same question here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572546/php-merge-arrays-with-only-not-duplicated-values

Comment: array_merge() will not remove duplicate entries....




[This link will help you to get rid of duplicate entries][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19088822/2667666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only **[array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge)** itself is not the answer to what you are looking for. After merging the arrays this question expects the duplicates to be removed (as shown in your expected output). Hence it would be

```
$a=array('a','b','c');
$b=array('a','d','e');

print_r(array_unique(array_merge($a,$b)));
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/Vq0PGsxl)**

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_merge & array_unique

```
$array_1 = array('a','b','c');
$array_2 = array('a','b','d','e');

$array = array_unique(array_merge($array_1, $array_2));
print_r($array);
```

you will get output as you want after **print_r**

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [5] => d
    [6] => e
)

or in php array

```
array('a','b','c','d','e');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_merge(array1, array2)
or using unary + operator
for eg:
1. using + operator:
`$array_1[0]=a;`
`$array_1[1]=;`
`$array_1[2]=c;`

`$array_2[0]=a;`
`$array_2[1]=b;`
`$array_2[3]=d;`
`$array_2[4]=e;`

`$arr_new=$array_1+$array_2;`
then print the $arr_new

2.using function
`$array_1=array("a","b","c");`
`$array_2=array("a","b","d","e");`
`print(array_merge($array_1,$array_2));`

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function

```
$output = array_merge($array_1, $array_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_merge` function

```
$beginning = 'foo';
$end = array(1 => 'bar');
$result = array_merge((array)$beginning, (array)$end);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the array union depending on the circumstances:

[+ operator for array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140090/operator-for-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The program with two arrays can be merged using this code

```
<?php
$array1= array("green","red");
$array2= array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($array1,$array2));
?>
```

Output will be:
Array([0]=>green[1]=>red[2]=>blue[3]=>yellow)

or use array_interlace()

```
<?php
$a=("a","b","c");
$b=("d","e","f");
print_r(array_interlace($a,$b));
?>
```

output will be:
Array(
[0]=>a[1]=>d[2]=>b[3]=>e[4]=>c[5]=>f)