# PHP unique array after merge

Tags: php

Is there a better way to achieve the following:

```
array_unique(array_merge($array_one, $array_two))
```

That is, merge two arrays and only have unique values.

array_merge seems to merge uniquely for keys, but i need unique values and can not see a built in function that does this.

I understand 'better' may be subjective.  Im thinking purely in the fact that im using two array functions wraped to get the values.

Comment: These are numeric arrays or associative?

Comment: `array_merge` does the right thing with numeric arrays, it just appends them.

Comment: yes, but i want only unique array values

Comment: `array_unique` does that.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this, AFAIK. You could write your own function to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: array\_merge & array\_unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660675/php-array-merge-array-unique)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do it in one fail swoop - two functions isn't bad though .. the only other suggestion is to slip in a condition when forming the second array ($array_two - or the last array formed), e.g.

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
   $array_one[] = $i;
}

for($k=5; $k<15; $k++) {
   if(!in_array($k,$array_one)) $array_two[] = $k;
}
```

Although of course if the first array isn't fully formed (finished) before the second array begins then this won't help. And if it takes too much delving to do this I would consider keeping the original - as long as it does what you want_g